lastValueFrom unreliable when refresh page
I have an Angular/Django app where, when I repeatedly refresh a page, in about 10% of cases, the result of lastValueFrom is empty. However, the rest of the time, I can see the correct data.
Here’s my code:
async ngOnInit() {
    this.goals$ = this.store.select(state => state.shortGoals.shortGoals);
    this.goals = await lastValueFrom(this.goals$.pipe(take(1)));

I have tried using delay, retry, and timeout, as well as a resolver, but the issue persists.

Smells like a race condition. Can you verify that store.select is consistently successful and returns a non-empty value?

async on ngOnInit() wouldn't make the Angular wait for it finish. Instead it would just be ignored. You're better off not converting the observable to a promise, and instead subscribing to the observable directly either using subscribe() or async pipe in the template.

Meh, that's the first time I hear not to use async on onInit, I'll think about it. Thx @Barremian

Could you try filter operator to allow only emissions that will have a value.
this.goals = await lastValueFrom(this.goals$.pipe(
  filter((data: any) => !!data),
  take(1),
);

If that does not work, you can also try subscribing to the observable and getting the data.
this.goals$.pipe(
  takeUntilDestroyed(),
  filter((data: any) => !!data),
  take(1),
).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.goals = data;
});


I have tried filter as well, it returned empty array, because it was initial state for reducer. However subscribe() works fine. Thnks.

I think a better approach would be to use the async pipe in the corresponding html to subscribe to the goals$ observable. It's not a good practice to use await in OnInit lifecycle hook.
Here is an example on how to do that:
<div *ngIf="goals$ | async as data; else loading">
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of data">{{ item }}</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
 <p>Loading Goals...</p>
</ng-template>


I am adding "blank goal" when data are really empty and use in p-table PrimeNG component, that's the reason why I decided to create goals it in *ts.
